# Problem in USB Ethernet driver Installation on Ubuntu 14.04LTS

Tags: drivers

I am facing problem while installing & loading USB ethernet drive (AX88179_178A).

I have downloaded ethernet drivers from [this link](http://www.asix.com.tw/FrootAttach/driver/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.12.0_SOURCE.tar.bz2).
After that I followed below procedure...

```
cd AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.12.0_SOURCE/

msil@mswelt29:~/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.12.0_SOURCE$ ls

ax88179_178a.c   ax88179_178a.h   Makefile   readme

msil@mswelt29:~/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.12.0_SOURCE$ make

msil@mswelt29:~/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.12.0_SOURCE$ ls

ax88179_178a.c  ax88179_178a.ko     ax88179_178a.mod.o  Makefile       Module.symvers
ax88179_178a.h  ax88179_178a.mod.c  ax88179_178a.o      modules.order  readme

msil@mswelt29:~/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.12.0_SOURCE$ sudo modprobe usbnet
msil@mswelt29:~/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.12.0_SOURCE$ sudo insmod ax88179_178a.ko

**insmod: ERROR: could not insert module ax88179_178a.ko: File exists**

msil@mswelt29:~/AX88179_178A_LINUX_DRIVER_v1.12.0_SOURCE$ locate ax88179_178a.ko

/lib/modules/3.13.0-24-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/ax88179_178a.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-34-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/ax88179_178a.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-35-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/ax88179_178a.ko
/lib/modules/3.13.0-36-generic/kernel/drivers/net/usb/ax88179_178a.ko
```

still after this execution my Ethernet adapter wont works.

Please suggest me right method.

Answer (score 0):

In my case on Debian Wheezy, I fixed it with building a new kernel.  Mine was 3.2.  Asix got their AX88179_178a driver put into kernel 3.9+ in Debian.  I see your on kernel 3.13 despite this. Can't answer why Ubuntu didn't include it in their kernel.

Wanted to fix it in my original kernel so as to not create any new breaks and learn how to fix the original problem.  No answers so the above was my fix.  So far everything works system wide despite the change to different kernel.

Would like a better answer than mine in case something similar comes up later on my system.